# Qual é a tradução do termo "sample" musical em português?

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução

Qual é a tradução do termo *sample* musical (ou *sampling*) (definição no [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sample), entry 2, sense 3) em português, no contexto da música em particular, mas não necessariamente (ou conceito de *sample* também é usado, por exemplo, no contexto de signal processing ou em estatística)?

Por exemplo, a canção *[Ó Mãe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOZAC2Mkoo8)* dos Iris (YouTube) *sampla* [*House of the Rising Sun* dos The Animals (YT)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uS90B4sZf7U). Na canção *House of the Rising Sun*, The Animals, em um determinado ponto da canção, também dizem "oh mother", portanto o sample não é só instrumental neste caso. Em outras palavras, *Ó Mãe* é uma canção que claramente se baseia sobre a famosíssima canção dos The Animals.

Sampling é usado muitíssimo no hip hop. Por exemplo, a canção [*Forever Young* de Jay-Z e Mr Hudson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4VkefYfVGR0) *sampla* [*Forever Young* de Alphaville](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1TcDHrkQYg), ou seja, *Forever Young* de Jay-Z baseia-se sobre (certas partes podem até ser idênticas) a melodia e texto da canção com o mesmo nome de Alphaville. O rapper Sam the Kid já usou o termo inglês *sample*, portanto é possível que não exista ainda uma tradução deste termo neste contexto.

Comment: Para a pergunta ter qualidade, deves definir claramente o que é um "sample". Podes usar inglês, colar definições do dicionário em inglês, etc - não tem problema. :)

Comment: [Ó mãe, aquele moce batê-me...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOZAC2Mkoo8) Obrigatório ouvir!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98324/discussion-on-question-by-nbro-qual-e-a-traducao-do-termo-sample-musical-em-po).

Answer (score 3):

Comumente se traduz para *amostra* e a ação de "samplear" para *amostragem*.

Mas usa-se também, por exemplo entre quem faz mixagens, o aportuguesamento *samplear*.

Fonte: Sou músico, leio muito material referente a música, artigos, manuais de instrumentos musicais eletrônicos, software musical traduzido para o português, etc.

Answer (score 0):

to sample a song

usar o trecho de uma música

Como se ve neste texto:

> Posso fazer ‘sample’ de músicas registradas, se o trecho tiver menos
> de 6 segundos? [...]
>
> Como ter responsabilidade jurídica com os “samples” (trechos de outros
> sons) que você usa na sua música [...]
>
> Para usar um trecho [to sample] de uma música registrada na sua
> própria música, você precisa ter DUAS licenças completamente
> diferentes:

[usar o trecho de uma música o de um son](http://Para%20usar%20um%20trecho%20de%20uma%20m%C3%BAsica%20registrada%20na%20sua%20pr%C3%B3pria%20m%C3%BAsica,%20voc%C3%AA%20precisa%20ter%20DUAS%20licen%C3%A7as%20completamente%20diferentes:)

Answer (score -1):

O mais sensato é "amostra", tanto por se tratar de partes da música, não dela como um todo, mas também levando em consideração o significado da palavra mesmo:

**2. pequena porção de alguma coisa dada para ver, provar ou analisar, a fim de que a qualidade do todo possa ser avaliada ou julgada.**

Comment: Erico, bem-vindo ao site. Mas *amostra* é usado no contexto em questão? Outra coisa, a parte em negrito é uma citação? Se sim, devias indicar a fonte.